# Typescript array initializing

Tags: arrays, typescript

`let s:number[][];`

How can I fill this `s` matrix as `0` of `n * n`.

`[[0, ..., 0], [0, ..., 0] ... [0, ..., 0]]`

This is what I'm doing

```
for(let i = 0;i < n;i ++) {
    let ss = [];
    for(let j = 0;j < n ;j ++)   ss.push(0);
    s.push(ss);
}
```

It's working but is there any more efficient and sophisticated way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `Array.from`:

```js
fillTwoDArray = (rows, columns,  defaultValue) => {
      return Array.from({ length:rows }, () => (
          Array.from({ length:columns }, ()=> defaultValue)
       ))
    }

console.log(fillTwoDArray(3, 7, 'foo'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array's `fill` method:

```
s = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n).fill(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const s = [...Array(n)].map(e => Array(n).fill(0))
```

I'm using this way!